# std::stack corrupts return value

Tags: c++, optimization, gcc, std-pair

I've reduced my code to the following to illustrate my problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <utility>

std::pair<double,double> test(double a, double b)
{
    std::stack<int> my_stack;
    return std::make_pair<double,double>(a,b);
}

int main()
{
    std::pair<double,double> p = test(1.1,2.2);
    std::cout << p.first << " " << p.second << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

The return value from the test() function gets corrupted when I use the gcc -O1 flag. Here is some sample output:

```
$ gcc -O2 a.cxx  -lstdc++
$ ./a.out
1.1 2.2
$ gcc -O1 a.cxx  -lstdc++
$ ./a.out
2.60831e-317 2.60657e-317
$ gcc -v
Reading specs from /usr/lib64/gcc-lib/x86_64-suse-linux/3.3.3/specs
Configured with: ../configure --enable-threads=posix --prefix=/usr --with-local-    prefix=/usr/local --infodir=/usr/share/info --mandir=/usr/share/man --enable-languages=c,c++,f77,objc,java,ada --disable-checking --libdir=/usr/lib64 --enable-libgcj --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/g++ --with-slibdir=/lib64 --with-system-zlib --enable-shared --enable-__cxa_atexit x86_64-suse-linux Thread model: posix
gcc version 3.3.3 (SuSE Linux)
```

This code works with all gcc optimazation flags except "-O1". It also works if I remove the declaration of my_stack. Would you classify this as a compiler bug, or am I missing something about std::stack and returning std::pair values?

Comment: By the way, the entire point of `make_pair` is to *not* specify the template arguments, and let them be deduced by the function arguments.

Comment: In other words, you could simply write `return std::make_pair(a,b)`. Since `a` and `b` are both doubles, it would *just work* (tm)

Answer (score 11):

Definitely a compiler bug.
BTW it is not reproduced with my GCC version (4.4.5).

The version of GCC 3.3.3 shipped with SuSE 9.1 is known to be broken (see [here](http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html#brokengcc)).

Comment: Also not reproduced by gcc 4.3.4 20090804 (release) 1.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bug. Check if the bug has been reported, if not, report it.

Comment: Take a note he is using an ancient version of gcc